# How can I get the toggleClass function to work correctly using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am creating headings that are appended after a p tag that is used as a place holder. Then I am adding a class for styling purposes. The problem comes in the click function that I am using to hide or unhide certain content. Each heading displays different content and by default I am hiding this content but when someone clicks on the heading it should hide or show content from a div by toggling the class "xx-hide". If I click on a heading it will show the content and if I click again it will hide it, all works well. **The problem is that if I click on a heading and then click on another heading without first hiding the previous one it starts acting weird displaying content from another heading or not displaying at all.**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var head1 = "<h5>Cyber Security</h5>";
    var head2 = "<h5>Computing Theory</h5>";
    var head3 = "<h5>Computer Systems</h5>";
    var head4 = "<h5>Artificial Intelligence/Machine Learning</h5>";
    var head5 = "<h5>Software Engineering</h5>";
    var head6 = "<h5>Network</h5>";
    $("p.placeholder").after(head1, head2, head3, head4, head5, head6);
    $("h5").addClass("research-headings");
    $("h5").eq(0).click(function() {
        $("div.res-info").toggleClass("cs-hide");
    });
    $("h5").eq(1).click(function() {
        $("div.res-info").toggleClass("ct-hide");
    });
    $("h5").eq(2).click(function() {
        $("div.res-info").toggleClass("cy-hide");
    });
    $("h5").eq(3).click(function() {
        $("div.res-info").toggleClass("ai-hide");
    });
    $("h5").eq(4).click(function() {
        $("div.res-info").toggleClass("se-hide");
    });
    $("h5").eq(5).click(function() {
        $("div.res-info").toggleClass("nt-hide");
    });
});
```

```css
.cs-hide {
    display: none;
}

.ct-hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Below is the first two of the six divs for the headings

<div class="res-head">
    <p class="placeholder"></p>
</div>
<div class="res-info cs-hide">
    <div style="width: 33%; height: 33%; font-weight: bold; text-align: left;">
        <p>The Department of Computer Science offers four tracks of study leading to an MS or PhD:</p>
        <ul class="res-list">
            <li class="res-list-item">- Information Assurance</li>
            <li class="res-list-item">- Intelligent Systems</li>
            <li class="res-list-item">- Networks and Telecommunications</li>
            <li class="res-list-item">- Traditional Computer Science</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <img src="cyberSecurity.jpeg" style="width: 33%; height: 33%;">
    <div style="width: 33%; height: 33%; font-weight: bold;">
        <p>Cyber Security Research in the UT Dallas CS department is conducted within the umbrella of the Cyber Security Research and Education Institute. Its origins go back to October 2004 when UTD’s Cyber Security Research Center (CSRC) was established soon after which it received the NSA/DHS Center of Academic Excellence designation in Information Assurance Education (CAEIAE) in June 2004. After receiving the NHA/DHS CAE in Research in 2008 and a $1.8 million Scholarship for Service (SFS) award from the NSF in 2010, our efforts and in cyber security research education were combined to establish Cyber Security Research and Education Center in January 2012. Subsequently, due to significant growth in faculty hiring, research and education in cyber security, the Cyber Security Research and Education Institute was established in April 2013.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="res-info ct-hide">
    <div style="width: 33%; height: 33%; font-weight: bold; text-align: left;">
        <p>The Department of Computer Science offers four tracks of study leading to an MS or PhD:</p>
        <ul class="res-list">
            <li class="res-list-item">- Information Assurance</li>
            <li class="res-list-item">- Intelligent Systems</li>
            <li class="res-list-item">- Networks and Telecommunications</li>
            <li class="res-list-item">- Traditional Computer Science</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <img src="computingTheory.jpeg" style="width: 33%; height: 33%;">
    <div style="width: 33%; height: 33%; font-weight: bold;">
        <p>The computing theory researchers in the Computer Science Department are focused on issues related to algorithms, combinatorics, graph theory, and cryptography. Key research areas include algorithms, combinatorics and optimization, computational biology, computational complexity, computational geometry, cryptography, and secure multiparty computations. There are a number of faculty members involved in this area. Research in the computing theory group is supported by the National Science Foundation (NSF).</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you inspect element and then see how it behaves on your clicks, you will notice the issue, there are many div.res-info elements which it tries to toggle.  not just the one you think you wanted.

Comment: Thank you, I changed each res-info class to be unique and it worked.

Comment: best would be in this case, use IDs, they are for this purpose of uniqueness and class are for multiple things